# Глюк или особенность библиотек по типу SwipeСards?

Tags: java, android, view, adapter

Пробовал использовать три разных библиотеки и и везде один глюк. Или я чего-то не понимаю?

[SwipeStack](https://github.com/flschweiger/SwipeStack) , [Swipecards](https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards) , [Swipe-Deck](https://github.com/aaronbond/Swipe-Deck)

Во всех трех есть некая сущность(`SwipeStack`) которую мы определяем в нашем `xml`. После чего создаем свой екземпляр `BaseAdapter` и в `getView()` формируем пердставления елементов. И пихаем их в наш стек.

```
mSwipeStack = (SwipeStack) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeStack);
mAdapter = new SwipeStackAdapter(mSwipeViewItems);
mSwipeStack.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Магия начинается после того как я пытаюсь программно изменить вид этих элементов после отображения на экране. Я ничего нового добавить не могу. Могу изменить только цвет елемента или текст в `textview` при этом `textview.height` изменить нельзя ни как.

В `getView()` можно добавить элементы таким образом и это работает:

```
 TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
 textView.setText("Text");
 textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
 layout.addView(textView);
```

А вот так уже нет:

```
layout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
           textView.setText("Text");
           textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
           layout.addView(textView);          
        }
 });
```

Или так уже нельзя. Ничего не происходит:

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = mExampleView.getViewTreeObserver();
viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
   @Override
   public void onGlobalLayout() {
       TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
       textView.setText("Text");
       textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 22);
       layout.addView(textView);    
   }
});
```

В обычной ситуации эти способы работа.т без проблем.
Даже кнокой добавить ничего нельзя. Аля `btn.onClick(){add textview}`

Что с этим миром не так? Рассудите плз.

Comment: Правильно я понимаю, что вы хотите изменять разметку элементов ListView?.. Если да, то лучше попробуйте на RecyclerView переделать. Не знаю как с вашими либами, но обычные вьюхи я там изменял программно (нажатие кнопки) и всё прекрасно работало.

Comment: `RecyclerView` предпологает, что я в качестве контейнера для элементов использовал `ListView`. Но как я уже сказал во все либах используется своя сущность и она даже не наследник `ListView`. И или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: Вы что-то путаете. ListView никак не связан с RecyclerView. Контейнером для элементов обоих служит любой наследник GroupView. Т.е. вы можете практически любой контейнер использовать для разметки элементов. В т.ч. ваши либы. При использовании RecyclerView вам нигде не придётся использовать ListView.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.sliderview/com.android.sliderview.ExampleActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android....$RecyclerViewAdapter cannot be cast to android.widget.Adapter` это когда я в `SwipeStack` адапртер пытаюсь запихнуть `RecyclerView`

Comment: При всем при этом `SwipeStack extends ViewGroup` который я использую в xml

Comment: Э-э-э... Т.е. эти либы суть обёртки над адаптером для ListView?.. Если так, то да - на RecyclerView переделать не удастся. Остаётся или переписывать либы или искать аналоги для RecyclerView.

Comment: Юрий, отож... вот и мучаюсь...

Comment: Да но почему не работает вы же сказали любой наследник `GroupView` , а `SwipeStack extends ViewGroup`

Comment: Я думал, что либы вы используете такие, которые используются как элементы разметки списка. А у вас - обёртка над адаптером + переопределённый ListView.